# unable to render view using backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document Router</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var documents = [
        new Backbone.Model({
          title: 'JavaScript Modules',
          content: 'why do we need modules? Organising JavaScript into modules makes it easier to reason about programs and makes it possible to test.'
        }),
        new Backbone.Model({
          title: 'Module Systems',
          content: 'There are three competing module systems at the moment: CommonJS, AMD and ECMAscript Harmony modules'
        })
      ]; 

      var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function () {
          this.$el.append(this.make('h1', null, this.model.get('title')));
          this.$el.append(this.make('div', null, this.model.get('content')));
          return this;
        }
      });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in console I have tried something like this:

```
var dv= new DocumentView();
undefined
dv.render();
```

and got the error like

> env.html:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
>   undefined(…)render @ env.html:51(anonymous function) @ VM359:1

what could be the issue and why I'm not able to render

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.model.get` inside the render method, but your view does not have a model defined hence the error. You should pass in a model instance while creating the view instance like

```
new DocumentView({model: document.models[0]})
```

or set `this.model = modelInstance` somewhere inside the view before it's rendered such as inside the `initialize` method for your code to work.

Also you haven't defined any `make` method on the view so `this.make` is likely to throw error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your model to your view while creating it.

```
var dv = DocumentView({
  model: documents[0] //Passing the first model
});

dv.render();
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumarabinash/C9wew/8250/).